# The product as the space of functions to the coproduct

Tags: category-theory

I recently had one of my "sun rises over Marblehead" moments when I realized that the elements of an arbitrary (Cartesian) product $\prod_{\alpha \in I}X_\alpha$ of sets can be thought as the set of all the *functions* from the index set $I$ to the *coproduct* $\coprod_{\alpha \in I}X_\alpha$.  (I.e. For all $x \in \prod_{\alpha \in I}X_\alpha$, $x$ is the function $I\to \coprod_{\alpha \in I}X_\alpha$ defined by $x(\beta) \mapsto \pi_\beta(x)$, where, $\forall \beta \in I$, $\pi_\beta$ is the canonical projection $\prod_{\alpha \in I}X_\alpha$ onto $X_\beta$.)

Admittedly, this is all rather vacuous, but it got me excited because it's the very first time that I have *ever* had an "endogenous" use for the notion of a coproduct, and I wonder if this particular use of the concept has anything to do with its role in category theory vis-à-vis products (the answer to which I expect will be "of course"), and if so, was this the *genesis* of the notion of a coproduct?

Comment: That's not correct. Not every map into the coproduct is of the form you mention.

Comment: Yeah, I hate to spoil the fun, but even when $I=2$ and $X_1, X_2$ each have one point, then $\prod_i X_i$ has cardinality 1, but $\coprod_i X_i$ has cardinality 2, and there are 4 functions from $I$ to $\coprod_i X_i$.

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is: $\prod_I X_\alpha$ can be identified with the set of functions $f : I \to \coprod_I X_\alpha$ which have the property that $f(\alpha) \in X_\alpha$?  You can think of such $f$ as choice functions if you like.

Comment: @ZhenLin: thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @NateEldredge: ditto

Comment: Elements of $\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ can be also viewed as the functions $f\colon I\to\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Also, there is the problem, that $I$ is a set, but $X_\alpha$ could be objects in *any category*. So that, $I\to\coprod X_\alpha$ is not really clear where it live..

Comment: Coproducts are just products in the opposite category. If you think taking products make sense, and if you also think taking the opposite of a category makes sense, then you think taking coproducts makes sense.

Comment: "was this the genesis of the notion of a coproduct?" Of course not!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: please forgive my loathsome stupidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting my comment so that this has an answer.

This claim is not true.  Take $I=2$ and $X_1, X_2$ to be singletons.  Then $\prod_i X_i$ has cardinality 1, but $\coprod_i X_i$ has cardinality 2, and there are 4 functions from $I$ to $\coprod_i X_i$.

You may be thinking of the fact that $\prod_i X_i$ can be identified with the set of functions $f : I \to \coprod_i X_i$ which satisfy the additional condition that $f(i) \in X_i$ for each $i \in I$.  Such functions are often called **choice functions**.